# How to keep 0 decimals using QGIS Field Calculator's "to_string"

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, field-calculator

Why does Field Calculator's `to_string` function rounds decimal numbers if they have zeros?

For example: `to_string(70.0)` gives `70` (textual). But I would need it to be `70.0`.

And as I have to convert an entire column which might have other values such as `70.1`, adding the `.0` manually is not going to be a solution to my problem.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, just found myself an answer, what a mess though...

`replace(to_string(format_number(70.0,1)), ',', '.')`

Basically:

`format_number(70.0,1)` gives numeric `70,0` (note the comma!)

`to_string(70,0)` converts it to textual `70,0`

Finally, `replace('70,0', ',', '.')` replace the comma to a dot giving the final textual `70.0` I needed.

Comment: to_string(format_number(<fieldname>,1)) worked fine for me. If you're having issues with commas instead of decimal points, that's a locale issue. Check under Settings -> Options... General